# tensorflow concat with transpose using the broadcast semantic

Tags: tensorflow, array-broadcasting

Say `v1` and `v2` has the same shape. Is it possible in tensorflow to concat `v1` and the **transposed** version of `v2` using the broadcast semantic?

For example,

```
v1 = tf.constant([[1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3],[5,5,5,5]])
v2 = tf.constant([[2,2,2,2],[4,4,4,4]])
```

I want to produce something like

```
[
 [[[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2]],
  [[1,1,1,1], [4,4,4,4]]],
 [[[3,3,3,3], [2,2,2,2]],
  [[3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]]],
 [[[5,5,5,5], [2,2,2,2]],
  [[5,5,5,5], [4,4,4,4]]]]
```

that is, with `v1` as `[3, 4]` and `v2` as `[2,4]`, I want to do

```
tf.concat([v1, tf.transpose(v2)], axis=0)
```

and produce a  `[3,2,2,4]` matrix.

Is there any trick for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by trick an elegant solution, I don't think so. However, a working solution would be to tile and repeat the incoming v1, v2

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [7, 7, 7, 7],
                  [5, 5, 5, 5]])
v2 = tf.constant([[2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [6, 6, 6, 6],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4]])


def my_concat(v1, v2):
    v1_m, v1_n = v1.shape.as_list()
    v2_m, v2_n = v2.shape.as_list()

    v1 = tf.concat([v1 for i in range(v2_m)], axis=-1)
    v1 = tf.reshape(v1, [v2_m * v1_m, -1])

    v2 = tf.tile(v2, [v1_m, 1])
    v1v2 = tf.concat([v1, v2], axis=-1)

    return tf.reshape(v1v2, [v1_m, v2_m, 2, v2_n])


with tf.Session() as sess:
    ret = sess.run(my_concat(v1, v2))

    print ret.shape
    print ret
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt to add two more elegant solutions to this Cartesian Product problem as follows (both tested); first one using [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [5, 5, 5, 5]])
v2 = tf.constant([[2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4]])

cartesian_product = tf.map_fn( lambda x: tf.map_fn( lambda y: tf.stack( [ x, y ] ), v2 ), v1 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( cartesian_product ) )
```

or this one taking advantage of the implicit broadcasting of add:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [5, 5, 5, 5]])
v2 = tf.constant([[2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4]])

v1, v2 = v1[ :, None, None, : ], v2[ None, :, None, : ]
cartesian_product = tf.concat( [ v1 + tf.zeros_like( v2 ),
                                 tf.zeros_like( v1 ) + v2 ], axis = 2 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( cartesian_product ) )
```

both output:

> [[[[1 1 1 1]
>     [2 2 2 2]]
>
> [[1 1 1 1]
>     [4 4 4 4]]]
>
> [[[3 3 3 3]
>     [2 2 2 2]]
>
> [[3 3 3 3]
>     [4 4 4 4]]]
>
> [[[5 5 5 5]
>     [2 2 2 2]]
>
> [[5 5 5 5]
>     [4 4 4 4]]]]

as desired.

Comment: `tf.map_fn` is just too slow (for GPU). Don't use that.